# using flexbox on ul (next to eachother)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I'm trying to use flexbox on my `<ul>` so I can align them next to eachother. When I use this `display:flex; flex-direction: row;` on my `<ul>` it will also effect the child (in this case all the `<li>`)

I tried giving the `<li>` a `display:flex;` aswell and `flex-direction: column;` but this did not help.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do here?
Look at my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n170zfLw/) for a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each `<ul>` displayed as a column next to each-other, you can wrap all of your `<ul>` inside of a div like so:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Best 1</li>
    <li>Best 2</li>
    <li>Best 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the 2 ul next to eachother but the li under eachother like a normal list. So first time Test list and at the right the Best list (float: right)

Comment: @Blank... I just updated my answer.  I think i misunderstood the problem.

Comment: This is what I meant thanks, so this is not possible without a div?

Comment: @Blank I don't really see a possibility to achieve this without putting everything inside a div. If you happen to find a solution that proves me wrong, please let em know.  Hope this helped regardless : )